# I want to stop this thread manually but couldn't find any way

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, mediarecorder

this thread automatically stops the media Recorder after 15 seconds.. I want to stop the thread manually also before 15 seconds when I click the stop button so what to do

```
recordstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            c=1;
            recordstart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recordstop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recordcomplete.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if(checkPermission()) {

                AudioSavePathInDevice =
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
                                CreateRandomAudioFileName(5) + "AudioRecording.3gp";

                MediaRecorderReady();

                try {
                    //mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(15000);
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    if (view.getId() == R.id.record) {
                        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                                        recordstart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        recordstop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        recordcomplete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Recording Completed",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }, 15000);

                    }

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Recording started",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }

        }
    });

    recordstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            recordstart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recordstop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recordcomplete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Recording Completed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

this is whole code

```
package com.dell.mubox;


ImageView recordstart, play, upload, recordstop, recordcomplete;
String AudioSavePathInDevice = null;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder ;
Random random ;
String RandomAudioFileName = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;
int c=0;
Timer t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

    recordstart = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.record);
    recordstop = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.recordstop);
    play = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play);
    upload = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.upload);
    recordcomplete = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.recordcomplete);

    random = new Random();

    recordstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            c=1;
            recordstart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recordstop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recordcomplete.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if(checkPermission()) {

                AudioSavePathInDevice =
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
                                CreateRandomAudioFileName(5) + "AudioRecording.3gp";

                MediaRecorderReady();

                try {
                    //mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(15000);
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    if (view.getId() == R.id.record) {
                        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                                        recordstart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        recordstop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        recordcomplete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Recording Completed",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }, 15000);

                    }

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Recording started",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }

        }
    });

    recordstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            recordstart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recordstop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recordcomplete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Recording Completed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                SecurityException, IllegalStateException {

            if (c == 1) {
                recordstart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recordstop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recordcomplete.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                try {
                    c = 0;
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AudioSavePathInDevice);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "No Audio Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Recording Playing",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Record Audio First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Audio Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

   /* buttonStopPlayingRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);
            buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(true);

            if(mediaPlayer != null){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                MediaRecorderReady();
            }
        }
    });*/

}

public void MediaRecorderReady(){
    mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);
}

public String CreateRandomAudioFileName(int string){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( string );
    int i = 0 ;
    while(i < string ) {
        stringBuilder.append(RandomAudioFileName.
                charAt(random.nextInt(RandomAudioFileName.length())));

        i++ ;
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UploadActivity.this, new
            String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO}, RequestPermissionCode);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RequestPermissionCode:
            if (grantResults.length> 0) {
                boolean StoragePermission = grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean RecordPermission = grantResults[1] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (StoragePermission && RecordPermission) {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Permission Granted",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

public boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            RECORD_AUDIO);
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error as why your current code does not work?

Comment: it says thread stopped at invalid state.... coz timer is set for 15 seconds so if we stop the recorder manually then this error occurs.